# How to make a character combination in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 3 letters A, B, and C, and I want to do a combination forming a string with this 3 characters but with 4 of length.

The results will be something like this:
`AAAA AAAB AABC`

Since `AAAA`, `BBBB` and `CCCC`, are a sample of a pattern, I need to know how many patterns has in these formed combinations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Solve my problem with this function

```
function Combinations(input, length, curstr) {
    if(curstr.length == length) return [ curstr ];
    var ret = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        ret.push.apply(ret, Combinations(input, length, curstr + input[i]));
    }
    return ret;
}

var input = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
console.log(Combinations(input, 4, ''));
```

and output will be like this

```
(81) ["aaaa", "aaab", "aaac", "aaba", "aabb", "aabc", "aaca", "aacb", "aacc", "abaa", "abab", "abac", "abba", "abbb", "abbc", "abca", "abcb", "abcc", "acaa", "acab", "acac", "acba", "acbb", "acbc", "acca", "accb", "accc", "baaa", "baab", "baac", "baba", "babb", "babc", "baca", "bacb", "bacc", "bbaa", "bbab", "bbac", "bbba", "bbbb", "bbbc", "bbca", "bbcb", "bbcc", "bcaa", "bcab", "bcac", "bcba", "bcbb", "bcbc", "bcca", "bccb", "bccc", "caaa", "caab", "caac", "caba", "cabb", "cabc", "caca", "cacb", "cacc", "cbaa", "cbab", "cbac", "cbba", "cbbb", "cbbc", "cbca", "cbcb", "cbcc", "ccaa", "ccab", "ccac", "ccba", "ccbb", "ccbc", "ccca", "cccb", "cccc"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (letter_one = 1; letter_one < 3; letter_one++) {
    for (letter_two = 1; letter_two < 3; letter_two++) {
        for (letter_three = 1; letter_three < 3; letter_three++) {
            console.log(String.fromCharCode(97 + letter_one) + String.fromCharCode(97 + letter_two) + String.fromCharCode(97 + letter_three));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maze, but i need combination just from a,b and c.